# How can I prevent Overflow for the Gamma function?

Tags: python, likelihood, dirichlet-distribution

I have a Dirichlet distribution from which I'm maximizing $\alpha$ by calculating the log likelihood with the following equation

$p\left(s|\alpha\right) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^O\log\left(\frac{n_i!}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^kn_{ij}!}\frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha_0\right)}{\Gamma\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^k\left(n_{ij}+a_j\right)\right)} \prod\limits_{j=1}^k \frac{\Gamma\left(n_{ij}+\alpha_j\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha_j\right)}\right)$

I have a python script to calculate the log likelihood. It works for small values, but when $n_{ij}$ gets high $\Gamma\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^k\left(n_{ij}+a_j\right)\right)$ and $\Gamma\left(n_{ij}+\alpha_j\right)$ python runs into overflow error (the max for math.gamma is between 171 and 172).

Is there a way to change the likelihood function so that $\Gamma\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^k\left(n_{ij}+a_j\right)\right)$ and $\Gamma\left(n_{ij}+\alpha_j\right)$ don't run into overflow errors. Can I just divide the values in $\Gamma$ by for example 100, if I then compare the likelihood between $p(s|\alpha)$ with different $\alpha$ values do the best $\alpha$ values still have the highest likelihood?

Comment: A common solution is to use a function which computes the log of gamma. I'd be surprised if there weren't already one in Python. Gamma is not a linear function - you can't just scale the *arguments* to gamma by the same constant and hope it cancels out.

Comment: Looking up the digamma function might be your best bet: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function

Comment: @Benjamin Could you explain how that solves the OP's problem?

Comment: @Glen_b python does have a log gamma function. I don't have the mathematical knowledge to know how changing the $\Gamma$ to log $\Gamma$ will affect the likelihood though. Can I just substitute them and still use the likelihood to maximimize $\alpha$?

Comment: log is a monotone increasing function so it should be fine.

Comment: log of a product is sum of the log.  Use log factorials too.

Comment: This question is asked in a different guise and answered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71030/performing-calculation-of-a-product-of-a-sequence. For complex calculations of this sort some caution concerning loss of precision is called for; that too is addressed in the other thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You suggest in comments that you don't know how the log-gamma function will work with the likelihood.

You need some basic facts:

1) log of a product of terms is the sum of the logs ($\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$)

2) log of a reciprocal is the negative of the log ($\log(1/c) = -\log(c)$)

3) The relationship between factorials and Gamma functions ($x! = \Gamma(x+1)$)

Using those three facts you just take the log inside that product (making it a sum of log-terms via rule 1), and apply rules 1,2, and 3 repeatedly until you have nothing but sums and differences of log-gamma functions inside the summation.

(This is not really a statistical issue at all, but a mathematical one, and the problem being solved is a computational one.)

If Python also has a function for the log of a binomial coefficient, you may be able to shave some time off your calculation.